# Is there anyway to use field name with concatenated from the url?

Tags: linq, llblgen

I am trying to search at the same time with pagination so I pass `fieldname` and `fieldvalue` to the url and get this. In the example below, I get the `fieldname` as 'firstName' and `fieldValue` as 'Jay'. Then I want to search like this but I get this error, ORM blah blah blah.. I am using LLBLgen as ORM but it seems it's more related to `linq`. Any ideas?

```
var sm ={
    FieldName:'firstName',
    FieldValue:'Jay'
}
```

```
orderModels = orderModels.Where(x => x + "." + sm.FieldName == sm.FieldValue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`System.Dynamic.Linq`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) package so that you can build query dynamically:

```
orderModels = orderModels.Where("@0 == @1",sm.FieldName, sm.FieldValue);
```

See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cs6MRX